# Removing elements from a binary python array whose neighborhood are less than N

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((10,16), dtype=np.int)
x[6:8,3:11] = 1
x[4:6,5:7] = 1
x[2:4,4:8] = 1
x[4:6,9:11] = 1
x[7,2] = 1
x[6,11] = 1
x[8,3] = 1
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

And I want to filter it so that elements in a 4 neighborhood (so, up, left, right, bottom) that have less than than 2 neighbors are removed. So, I'd end up with (last three positions set as one removed):

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I tried using `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_closing`, `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_opening`, `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation` and `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion`, but the result isn't what I need. I could make 2 for loops and iterate over each element of the array, checking for the neighbor elements, but I feel like there's a better way to do this. Am I mistaken?

I'm more interested in this specific situation (4 neighborhood, keep 2 neighbors), but is it easy to generalize to another neighborhood or number of neighbors (assuming a binary array)?

Comment: Is this all at once, or incremental, for example, if removing one neighborhood causes another neighborhood to meet the condition, should that be removed as well?

Comment: Maybe 2d convolve with `[0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]`. Take a look at https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/07/conways-game-of-life/ or other game of life implementations in sci/numpy for inspiration

Comment: 1 pass. If it removes neighbors and causes others to meet the condition, it is fine to keep them. I tried `scipy.signal.convolve2d` but it doesn't do anything close to what I need.

Comment: Actually, I managed to get it done with convolutions, though I'm not sure if it was a coincidence or how to generalize it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Please post your answer as a self-answer instead of editing your question so it gets marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done like this:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
kernel = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]
filtered = convolve2d(x, kernel, mode='same')
x[filtered<=2] = 0
```

Filtered:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 3 4 4 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 3 5 5 3 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 2 4 4 2 1 3 3 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 2 4 4 2 2 4 4 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 3 4 5 5 4 4 5 5 2 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

And I got the output I wanted. Thank you @user3080953